# What type of hardware is this

Tags: hardware-identification

... that allows the steps to collapse and the support brace to pivot inwards so that the unit can lay flat? Some sort of bolt?

[image: pet_steps]

[image: pet_steps2]

[image: pet_steps3]

Comment: https://youtu.be/TnfkdLHKwBU Here is one way to build them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dowels.

This could be done multiple ways but I'd say there's a good chance the tread and the riser pivot on dowels. This is the simplest way to make anything like this where a component needs to rotate about an axis, although you could use steel pins* for increased strength and durability a wood-only solution can be strong enough and durable enough for a long service life. The key thing then would be the diameter and strength of the wood used for the dowel.

---

*Housed directly in wood or in bushings of plastic or metal